Why does converting an old datetime to EST on Windows offset time by an additional ~18 minutes?
Consider the following:
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

dt = datetime(1677, 9, 22, 5, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
print(dt.astimezone(ZoneInfo("EST")))

On my MacOS machine this prints 1677-09-22 00:00:00-05:00 as expected. On my Windows 11 machine it prints 1677-09-21 23:41:52-05:18:08.
While I acknowledge that a specific timezone like EST doesn't really make much sense for a datetime that old, I'm still very puzzled as to why the offset has increased by ~18 minutes, and only on Windows.
The exact same datetime in 2024 converts as expected on both platforms.
EDIT: I'm perfectly aware that the systems can have different timezone databases. I'd like to know what caused specifically a non-integer hour offset of ~18 minutes.

"By default, zoneinfo uses the system’s time zone data if available." — The underlying zone data is probably different between different systems in those gray areas. Request undefined data, get undefined results…

On my windows 11 I get 1677-09-22 00:00:00-05:00

@Guy It reproduces for me on Windows 11 Pro, build 22631.4037.

I found this answer here .This question is quite similar to your question.

That does not explain why there is a mysterious shift of 18 minutes in the past.

My build version is 22631.4169, it's hard to believe this minor difference is the cause.

I think the answer is pretty obvious.
Linux and OSX both use the IANA time zone database...Windows, on the other hand, does not have that history for this time zone...That means Windows is not aware of any historical differences in DST rules, and thus treats every year the under the same set of rules.

@Guy Changing the local timezone on this machine made it stop reproducing... I guess it must've triggered some timezone database update?

@orlp I guess it's possible.

"I'd like to know what caused specifically a non-integer hour offset of ~18 minutes" — What kind of answer do you expect here? Before timezones were widely standardised, even neighbouring towns may have had offsets of a few minutes to hours. This is sometimes reflected in historical timezones. A weird offset for historical dates is perfectly expected.

@deceze An answer along those lines would be what I expect, ideally with a reference to the specific reason for the offset for that timezone but that's for bonus points.

@Guy Actually, I messed up a virtual environment, the local timezone had nothing to do with it. Try pip install --upgrade tzdata, on my machine it reproduces with tzdata==2024.2 but not earlier versions. So it seems this is a 'recent' update to the IANA database that causes this shift, and the Linux/MacOS databases are probably out of date.
